# Is the implied volatility in QuantLib independent of the pricing engine?

Tags: quantitative-finance, quantlib, volatility

This might be a stupid question as I just started looking into QuantLib.  (I'm using the python API.)  It seems that the implied volatility calculation does not require a pricing engine.  If so, which pricing engine is used?  I am interested in the implied volatility of American options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the option cannot reuse the same engine set to the instrument. This is because it needs to create a new engine, in which the volatility is flat and under the control of the method (since it needs to be changed by the solver). This can't be done in a generic way, especially considering that users might implement entirely new engines.

All the method can do is return an estimate based on one chosen engine. The default chosen is `FdBlackScholesVanillaEngine` with default parameters.  If you want to use a different engine, or the same engine with different parameters, you'll have to duplicate the code inside the method.